# How should "double-consciousness" be interpreted in this passage?

Tags: sentence-meaning, literature

> It is a peculiar sensation, this double-consciousness, this sense of always looking at one’s self through the eyes of others, of measuring one’s soul by the tape of a world that looks on in amused contempt and pity. One ever feels his two-ness, – an American, a Negro; two souls, two thoughts, two unreconciled strivings; two warring ideals in one dark body, whose dogged strength alone keeps it from being torn asunder

This sentence is from Du Bois' book, *The Soul Of Black Folk*.

This seems to mean that black Americans have both an American self and a black self, but the previous part is too difficult to interpret.
Can you help me interpret it?

Comment: The meaning is clearly spelled out in the text and your question is not really related to our concerns here. You use a tape measure to measure things.

Comment: I thought the Question and the passage quoted were about literature, not language. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

The key to the meaning is this:

> this sense of always looking at one's self through the eyes of others...

A person knows what he is in a simple way, but he also knows that others regard him with contempt; as a social being, he must consider the views of others, especially if they have power over him, and those views make a measuring-tape that has its effect on his consciousness, regardless of its mindless injustice. So, he feels his two-ness.

Comment: Sorry, but this answer completely ignores, if not trivializes, the Black experience in America and gives a run-of-the-mill reading of the sentence. The explanation doesn't work in this context.